# I have used the correct syntax of jquery but still isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This jQuery form validation is not working. When I click on the <s>submit</s> button the `Submit2` function isn't doing any validation. I'm sure I used the correct syntax and correct order of the loading of jQuery.

```
<div id="signup_teacher">
<form class="form_signin" id="teacher-form" method="post" action="">
<h2 class="form_signin_heading signin_header">Signup.</h2>
            <div class="field" data-fieldname="name">
                <div class="prompt_name">
                    <input type="text" required="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prompt_email">
                <div class="field" data-fieldname="email">
                    <input type="email" required="" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Email" id="email2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prompt_teacher_id">
                <div class="field" data-fieldname="teacher_id">
                    <input type="number" required="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="7" placeholder="Id" id="idno2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prompt_password">
                <div class="field" data-fieldname="password">
                    <input type="password" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" id="pswrd2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group sign-up-box">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary " id="submit2" onclick="Submit2">Submit</button>
            </div>

    </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    function Submit2()
    {
        var fullname2=$("#fullname2").val();
        var email2=$("#email2").val();
        var idno2=$("#idno2").val();
        var pswrd2=$("#pswrd2").val();


        if($("#fullname2").val()="")
        {
              $("#fullname2").focus();
                return false;
        }
        if($("#email2").val()="")
        {
            $("#email2").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if($("#idno2").val()="")
        {
            $("#idno2").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if($("#pswrd2").val()="")
        {
              $("#pswrd2").focus();
            return false;
        }

    }


});
```

Comment: **Two things:** #1 Change `onclick="Submit2"` ==> `onclick="return Submit2()"` #2 Move the function `Submit2` outside of `ready()` to make it global

Comment: You should let htm5 constraint validation kick in and let that do everything for you. No need to write any client side validation yourself. Besides, you are doing it a lite wrong, You should use onSubmit on the form and use `peventDefault` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to use double equals `==` or triple equals `===` to check for a condition in `if` statements. a single `=` is a assignment
- Your html has one to many `</div>` in the end
- You can use `autocomplete="off"` on the form instead of doing it on every form element
- You should use `form#onSubmit` instead of `button#onClick` to let [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) kick in. But to do so you should change the button to `type="submit"` from `type="button"`, wish you should do anyway
  Now you don't need to do any validation yourself! Woho!
- You don't need the empty value `=""` on attributes just by having `required` is enough.
- And last of all let the javascript handle the event registration part and don't do any onclick or simular on the html attributes, It could actually be safer that way if you use [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy) or inserting any dynamic html templates specified by the user.
  Besides, then you don't have to cloture down the global window scope and accidentally override something. You want to avoid putting as much as you can on the global scope

```js
// short for document ready
// https://api.jquery.com/ready/
jQuery($ => {

    // Here we use form#onSubmit instead of button click to
    // let the constraint validation kick in
    $('#teacher-form').on('submit', evt => {
        // Disable default behaviour (stop from submitting)
        evt.preventDefault()
        // This should always be true... since this only happens when the form is valid
        let valid = evt.target.checkValidity() ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
        alert('The form is ' + valid)
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="signup_teacher">
  <form class="form_signin" id="teacher-form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <h2 class="form_signin_heading signin_header">Signup.</h2>

    <div class="field" data-fieldname="name">
      <div class="prompt_name">
        <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname2">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="prompt_email">
      <div class="field" data-fieldname="email">
        <input type="email" required placeholder="Email" id="email2">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="prompt_teacher_id">
      <div class="field" data-fieldname="teacher_id">
        <input type="number" required maxlength="7" placeholder="Id" id="idno2">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="prompt_password">
      <div class="field" data-fieldname="password">
        <input type="password" required placeholder="Password" id="pswrd2">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group sign-up-box">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit2">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . It was really helpful , as i'm a starter and didn't know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

the `onclick` needs the function to be available in the global window scope. However you have placed the function inside `document.ready` so it is not accessible in global scope. Using your browser console you should see error thrown that `Submit2` is undefined (or not a function).

Since you are using jQuery it would be simpler to use a jQuery event handler and remove `onclick` from the html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function Submit2() {
    // your existing function code
  }

  $('#teacher-form').on('submit', Submit2);

});
```

Comment: Instead of `click` on submit button, `submit` event on `form` is better, also handles Enter key press to submit form from any input.

Comment: @Tushar I totally agree and make that same comment a lot myself. I didn't really look close at html to even see what it was. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to change. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e500ydsj/)**

1. You have declared the function `submit2()` inside the `document.ready` which won't be visible to window scope, hence you can remove onclick submit function from the html and **call the function onclick of submit in jQuery using the button id**
2. You need to use `"=="` double equals to check for a condition

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary " id="submit2" >Submit</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


  $('#submit2').click(function()
{
    var fullname2=$("#fullname2").val();
    var email2=$("#email2").val();
    var idno2=$("#idno2").val();
    var pswrd2=$("#pswrd2").val();


    if($("#fullname2").val()=="")
    {
          $("#fullname2").focus();

            return false;
    }
    if($("#email2").val()=="")
    {
        $("#email2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if($("#idno2").val()=="")
    {
        $("#idno2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if($("#pswrd2").val()=="")
    {
          $("#pswrd2").focus();
        return false;
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JavaScript and jquery. use `.click()` event handler on button and secondly change '=' to '==' in if statement.

```js
    $('#submit2').click(function() {
     var fullname2=$("#fullname2").val();
        var email2=$("#email2").val();
        var idno2=$("#idno2").val();
        var pswrd2=$("#pswrd2").val();


        if($("#fullname2").val()=="")
        {
              $("#fullname2").focus();
                return false;
        }
        else if($("#email2").val()=="")
        {
            $("#email2").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if($("#idno2").val()=="")
        {
            $("#idno2").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if($("#pswrd2").val()=="")
        {
              $("#pswrd2").focus();
            return false;
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="signup_teacher">
<form class="form_signin" id="teacher-form" method="post" action="">
<h2 class="form_signin_heading signin_header">Signup.</h2>
            <div class="field" data-fieldname="name">
                <div class="prompt_name">
                    <input type="text" required="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prompt_email">
                <div class="field" data-fieldname="email">
                    <input type="email" required="" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Email" id="email2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prompt_teacher_id">
                <div class="field" data-fieldname="teacher_id">
                    <input type="number" required="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="7" placeholder="Id" id="idno2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prompt_password">
                <div class="field" data-fieldname="password">
                    <input type="password" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" id="pswrd2">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group sign-up-box">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary " id="submit2">Submit</button>
            </div>

    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using <... onclick="someFns"> to register a handle, the someFns must be accessible in the global scope. However, in your code, 'Submit2' function is inside a anonymous function, and JS using function scope, so the 'Submit2' function can only be reached inside the anonymous function.

If you want to use the <... onclick...> way to register handler, make 'Submit2' a global function.

Another way you can register the function :

```
$(function(){
function Submit2 () {
...
}
$('#submit2').click(Submit2);
})
```

Another thing, what do you expect the return value doing?